# remove unused css from responsive page

Tags: css, responsive-design, code-cleanup

I have built a "responsive" website using by combining blocks from several different templates.
The problem now is that the css file is 5,000 lines and chrome suggests %84 of my css is unused.
Ive tried to remove unused css by using a couple different firefox plugins. The problem is the output css file looses its responsive properties. What is the best way for cleaning this up?

link to website
http://buyfuelpump.com/shop.php?u=fuelpumps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split your CSS Files into several (for different display sizes)

And then use (for example):

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="yourfile.css">
```

Comment: What bracket of different sizes do you suggest?

Comment: I would use the same sizes as in Bootstrip.  http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: Just last question here, with this method, if a desktop user resizes windows screen, or perhaps mobile user filps the phone horizontally  will it fail to be responsive?